# Searching for a string in a struct

Tags: c, string, search, struct

The code below is a code that will track my product costs and remaining quantity.The problem I'm facing with is I can't search the code by

```
if(g[n].name == search[10])
```

The out put keep showing

> "Item not found"

Im a beginner of c language and was hope to learn more. Please correct my code and send it here so that I can know why my code is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct product
{
    char name[10];
    int quantity;
    float costs;
};

void fn_search (struct product g[]);

int main ()
{
    int n;

    struct product g[4];

    strcpy(g[0].name,"aa1");
    g[0].quantity = 10;
    g[0].costs = 1;

    strcpy(g[1].name,"bb2");
    g[1].quantity = 10;
    g[1].costs = 2;

    strcpy(g[2].name,"bb3");
    g[2].quantity = 10;
    g[2].costs = 3;

    fn_search (g);
}

void fn_search (struct product g[10])
{
    int n;
    char search[10];
    printf("Search>> ");
    scanf("%s",&search[10]);

    for (n=0;n<4;n++)
        {
            if(g[n].name == search[10])
                {
                   printf ("\ncosts = NTD%.2f",g[n].costs);
                    printf ("\nquantity = %d\n",g[n].quantity);
                }
            else
                {
                    printf("\nItem not found.");
                    break;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: To compare strings you must use `strcmp()`

Comment: You are not doing string comparison with that if statement. You are comparing two pointers.

Comment: even i use strcmp
 
   for (n=0;n<4;n++)
        {
            if(strcmp( g[n].name,search[10])==0)
                {
                   printf ("\ncosts = NTD%.2f",g[n].costs);
                    printf ("\nquantity = %d\n",g[n].quantity);
                }
            else
                {
                    printf("\nItem not found.");
                    break;
                }
        }


i get weird output, it skipped the if-else statement

Comment: I know this is not related to your question.  But if you declare `char search[10]`, the index is from 0 to 9. If you try to use `search[10]`, it is out of bound.

Comment: @Brian [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) take pointers as input parameters, `search[10]` is a char not a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two bugs:

Incorrect use of `scanf` :

```
scanf("%s",&search[10]);  --> scanf("%9s", search);
```

Note: `scanf("%9s", &search[0]);` is also fine but the above is the common way.

Incorrect string compare :

```
if(g[n].name == search[10]) --> if(strcmp(g[n].name, search) == 0)
```

Also notice that you never initialized `g[3]` but `fn_search` checks it.

Then this part:

```
        else
            {
                printf("\nItem not found.");
                break;
            }
```

means that you break the `for` loop as soon as an item doesn't match. In other words: Currently you only compare against `g[0]`

You don't want that! Check all items before printing "Item not found".

So the `for` loop should be more like:

```
for (n=0;n<4;n++)
{
    if(strcmp(g[n].name, search) == 0)
    {
        printf ("\ncosts = NTD%.2f",g[n].costs);
        printf ("\nquantity = %d\n",g[n].quantity);

        return;  // Exit function when match is found
    }
}

// When execution arrives here, there was no matching element
printf("\nItem not found.");
```

Finally:

```
void fn_search (struct product g[10])
                                 ^^
                                 why ??
```

Either do

```
void fn_search (struct product g[])
```

or

```
void fn_search (struct product *g)
```

Comment: hmm, i have a few questions about the // scanf("%9s", search) // why we don't use "&" to store the data we inputting? rlly appreciate it.

Comment: @brian Because you want the scan'ed data to be placed in an array. An array like `char search[10];` when used as `searc` in function calls automatically decays to a pointer (which is what `scanf` expects. You could just as well do: `&search[0]` **Notice - zero!! not 10`.**